# How to make a tool from python.py script?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have been self-learning python from webpages and plan to make a tool from my python scripts. The aim is for other people who doesn't need to install python into their computer and just run the python script/tool that I have written. Just as simple as double click it and enter an input.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What operating system(s) is this targeted for?

Comment: pyinstaller,py2exe,or cxfreeze ... Im not sure which support 3.5 off hand

Comment: @Colin Mac OS v10.10 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.  If you don't want your end users to have to install python, or just don't want to depend on other users' system python, you can use [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [`py2app`](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) to bundle up your script, all dependencies, and a python interpreter.  You would use `py2exe` for windows users and `py2app` for mac users.

Both packages require you to learn a little bit about python packaging.  You'll need to create a proper [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#writing-the-setup-script) script for your package/module.

Comment: Thanks @Brendan will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584270/how-do-you-make-a-python-executable-file-on-mac)

If you are on mac you need to include a shebang and make the script executeable